# Screen session started from rc.local is not visible in screen -ls under root

Tags: gnu-screen

On CentOS 7.

I have edited /etc/rc.d/rc.local, and made it executable, and I am starting a screen session from it.

Problem is, when I log to server as root, I am not seeing screen sessions started from rc.local, under `screen -ls` run as root user.

If I do `ps axuf | grep -i screen`, I see screen sessions are active, and I can see processes inside screen are running.

How do I attach myself to this screen sessions?

My rc.local section for screen looks something like this.

```
/usr/bin/screen -wipe
/usr/bin/screen -dmS scr1 /script/rsync1.sh
/usr/bin/screen -dmS scr2 /script/rsync2.sh
/usr/bin/screen -dmS scr3 /script/rsync3.sh
/usr/bin/screen -dmS scr4 /script/rsync4.sh
/usr/bin/screen -dmS scr5 /script/rsync5.sh
```

I can see screen sessions are started with `ps auxf` after server boot.

```
root@server [~]# ps auxf | grep -i screen
root       90642  0.0  0.0 112648   988 pts/0    S+   21:54   0:00          \_ grep --color=auto -i screen
root        3384  0.0  0.0 127784  2212 ?        Ss   21:33   0:00 /usr/bin/SCREEN -dmS scr1 /script/rsync1.sh
root        3390  0.0  0.0 127784  2252 ?        Ss   21:33   0:00 /usr/bin/SCREEN -dmS scr2 /script/rsync2.sh    
root        3393  0.0  0.0 127784  2252 ?        Ss   21:33   0:00 /usr/bin/SCREEN -dmS scr3 /script/rsync3.sh
root        3398  0.0  0.0 127784  2252 ?        Ss   21:33   0:00 /usr/bin/SCREEN -dmS scr4 /script/rsync4.sh
root        3403  0.0  0.0 127784  2248 ?        Ss   21:33   0:01 /usr/bin/SCREEN -dmS scr5 /script/rsync5.sh
```

If i try to do `screen -r scr1`, I will get that there is no such screen running.

Sessions are running as root, so I am not sure why am I not able to see them.

I have tried adding /usr/bin/sudo to beginning of commands, but then it fails to start completely.

```
Jul 10 22:07:37 server systemd[1]: Starting /etc/rc.d/rc.local Compatibility...
Jul 10 22:07:39 server rc.local[3645]: sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo
Jul 10 22:07:39 server rc.local[3645]: sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo
Jul 10 22:07:39 server rc.local[3645]: sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo
Jul 10 22:07:39 server rc.local[3645]: sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo
Jul 10 22:07:39 server rc.local[3645]: sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo
Jul 10 22:07:39 server systemd[1]: rc-local.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jul 10 22:07:39 server systemd[1]: Failed to start /etc/rc.d/rc.local Compatibility.
Jul 10 22:07:39 server systemd[1]: Unit rc-local.service entered failed state.
Jul 10 22:07:39 server systemd[1]: rc-local.service failed.
```

Also, the `screen -wipe` on the start, doesn't seem to affect sessions that were started manually outside rc.local.

In case server crashes, screens that were started manually will still be shown as dead in `screen -ls` under root.

I have added this to rc.local, and not to crontab with @reboot, because that would not work in case system crashes or gets powered off/shutdown without reboot, it would only get triggered on reboots, as far as I understand @reboot in cron.

Solved by Stephen Harris comment about $SCREENDIR.

> In your startup script do a screen -ls > /tmp/xyzzy.$$ (or similar
>   filename) - that'll tell you what directory it has stored the sockets
>   in. You may need to set $SCREENDIR to point to this directory in order
>   to see the sessions when trying to re-attach. – Stephen Harris 10
>   hours ago

rc.local used `/var/run/screen/S-root` as SCREENDIR

root used `/root/screens` as SCREENDIR, which is why it didn't see sessions from rc.local

Note:

It is not needed to add screen -ls > /tmp/xyzzy.$$ to rc.local to find which folder is used as SCREENDIR. 
It can be seen by doing `systemctl status rc-local`, it will show something like this in output

```
rc.local[3258]: No Sockets found in /var/run/screen/S-root.
```

After doing `export SCREENDIR=/var/run/screen/S-root` `screen -ls` shows screens started from rc.local

Comment: imo, you should not be using `/usr/bin/SCREEN` in your rc.local , you should use `/usr/bin/screen`

Comment: it is /usr/bin/screen in rc.local it is only /usr/bin/SCREEN in ps output, I corrected the question.

Comment: The `screen -wipe` should be unnecessary. You don't have another `screen wipe` that runs after your `rc.local`?

Comment: screen -wipe is to remove dead screens in case system crashes. In case of system crash server resets with dead screen sessions.

Comment: In your startup script do a `screen -ls > /tmp/xyzzy.$$` (or similar filename) - that'll tell you what directory it has stored the sockets in.  You may need to set `$SCREENDIR` to point to this directory in order to see the sessions when trying to re-attach.

Comment: I know what `screen -wipe` does, thank you, which is why I'm suggesting you remove it, and asking you to check there isn't another one after your screens start.

Comment: Tried removing it, but nothing changed, also the one that is in rc.local doesn't remove dead screens that were started manually, after system crashes, I just had one server crash, and dead screens are still there for sessions that were started manually, and new ones started by rc.local are not shown in screen -ls, only dead ones

Comment: Solved by Stephen Harris comment about $SCREENDIR. Note: it is not needed to add screen -ls > /tmp/xyzzy.$$ to rc.local to find which folder is used as SCREENDIR, it can be seen by doing systemctl status rc-local, it show something like this in output "rc.local[3258]: No Sockets found in /var/run/screen/S-root. "  After doing export SCREENDIR=/var/run/screen/S-root screen -ls shows screens started from rc.local

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by Stephen Harris comment about $SCREENDIR.

> In your startup script do a screen -ls > /tmp/xyzzy.$$ (or similar
>   filename) - that'll tell you what directory it has stored the sockets
>   in. You may need to set $SCREENDIR to point to this directory in order
>   to see the sessions when trying to re-attach. – Stephen Harris 10
>   hours ago

rc.local used `/var/run/screen/S-root` as SCREENDIR

root used `/root/screens` as SCREENDIR, which is why it didn't see sessions from rc.local

Note:

It is not needed to add screen -ls > /tmp/xyzzy.$$ to rc.local to find which folder is used as SCREENDIR. 
It can be seen by doing `systemctl status rc-local`, it will show something like this in output

```
rc.local[3258]: No Sockets found in /var/run/screen/S-root.
```

After doing `export SCREENDIR=/var/run/screen/S-root` `screen -ls` shows screens started from rc.local